# How to make a two decimal places on the result of a sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code.

```
 SELECT SUM(receivables) AS [Trans-January], 
        (SELECT SUM(receivables)
         FROM tbl_customerInfo 
         WHERE invalid = 'valid'
            AND YEAR(currentDate) = '2017'
            AND MONTH(currentDate) = '02'
            AND paid = 1) AS [Coll-January],
      (((SELECT SUM(receivables)
         FROM tbl_customerInfo
         WHERE invalid = 'valid'
            AND YEAR(currentDate) = '2017'
            AND MONTH(currentDate) = '02'
            AND paid = 1) / 
        (SELECT SUM(receivables)
         FROM tbl_customerInfo
         WHERE invalid = 'valid'
            AND YEAR(currentDate) = '2017'
            AND MONTH(currentDate) = '02')) *100) AS [Coll - january]
FROM tbl_customerInfo
WHERE invalid = 'valid'
AND YEAR(currentDate) = '2017'
AND MONTH(currentDate) = '02'
```

I am getting results of

```html
<table border = 1>
<thead>
<th>Trans - January</th>
<th>Coll - January</th>
<th>January %</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>598641.25</td>
<td>6523.21</td>
<td>1.089669313633165</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How am I going to make the results from the column January % show only 4 decimal places? (xxxxx.xxxx)

In addition, can you help me improve my code? I am going to get all those three columns from January - December. In short, 36 columns in total.

Comment: If I were asking a question about this query, I would ask how to simplify it.  It is way more complicated and slower than necessary.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. Can you help me simply this query because I am about to do this for the whole year. January, February, March......so on. 36 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to simplify this code - but for the decimals - The following uses the Format function to get 4 decimal places. (Your title says 2 decimal places, but your notes say 4).

```
Declare @currentDate Date
Set @currentDate = '2017-02-25'  --GetDate()

 SELECT 
   SUM(receivables) AS [Trans-January], 

       (SELECT SUM(receivables)
         FROM tbl_customerInfo 
         WHERE invalid = 'valid'
            AND YEAR(@currentDate) = '2017'
            AND MONTH(@currentDate) = '02'
            AND paid = 1) AS [Coll-January],
Format(
      (((SELECT SUM(receivables)
         FROM tbl_customerInfo
         WHERE invalid = 'valid'
            AND YEAR(@currentDate) = '2017'
            AND MONTH(@currentDate) = '02'
            AND paid = 1) / 
        (SELECT SUM(receivables)
         FROM tbl_customerInfo
         WHERE invalid = 'valid'
            AND YEAR(@currentDate) = '2017'
            AND MONTH(@currentDate) = '02')) *100) 
,'N4')  AS [January]

FROM tbl_customerInfo
WHERE invalid = 'valid'
AND YEAR(@currentDate) = '2017'
AND MONTH(@currentDate) = '02'
```

Comment: Thanks. I am now getting the error : "Specified cast is not valid" when trying to get the value of [January %] and put it in a string type variable with this code -> 
string percentJan = dr.GetDouble(dr.GetOrdinal("January %")).ToString();

Comment: Okay i get it. FORMAT func formats values as strings. THanks! I'm gonna try this